# Oracle date format validation

Tags: oracle, date

I have a varchar column in the table which contains the date value. 
i need to consider only the dates which is in YYYYMMDD format. How do i verify the value is in YYYYMMDD format.

IS_date function is not available in Oracle to validate whether the value is a valid date or not?

Comment: In Oracle 12.2 you have such function: [VALIDATE_CONVERSION](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/VALIDATE_CONVERSION.html)

Answer (score 2):

Try to create a user-defined function for this, as there is no is_date function is available in Oracle

```
create function valid-date(d varchar2) return varchar2
is
  v_date date;
begin
  select to_date(d,'yyyymmdd') into v_date from dual;
  return 'Valid';
  exception when others then return 'Invalid';
end;
```

You can check the function like,

```
select your_date_col, valid-date(your_date_col)
from your_table
```